# Is it possible to use AForge libraries in Windows Forms Control Library?

Tags: c#, user-controls, aforge, dynamic-usercontrols

I have a Windows Forms Control Library called "UserControlTest" (I'm practicing with it right now) and I am trying to use some of the AForge Libraries Controls on it.  It lets me put them on the design and doesn't have any errors after building the solution, but when I try to run it it says

> Failed to create UserControl 'UserControlTest.UserControl1'
>
> The error message was 'Could not load file or assembly 'AForge.Video, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cbfb6e07d173c401' or one of its dependencies.  Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515')

I need the AForge libraries for this particular user control, but there is this problem.  I want the libraries in the user control because I need to programmatically create this user control 2 or 3 times (sometimes more, sometimes less, so it needs to be dynamic). Is this not possible?  I thought it would still work since it is still a windows form. I can show my code, but I don't think that would help since there are no errors in the code.

Comment: AForge.NET should work with Windows Forms. Are you using NuGet to add the references? Which version of .NET Framework are you targeting?

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010.  Using NuGet to add the references?  I do Project>Add References...  I don't think AForge works in UserControls.  I'm wondering if someone knows for sure though.

Comment: I recommend that you use NuGet to reference the required AForge packages; NuGet takes care of any third-party dependencies for you. If you are using VS 2010, please see [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget) for info on how to install the NuGet plug-in. Once you have NuGet installed, use the NuGet package manager to locate the online [AForge packages](http://www.nuget.org/profiles/aforge.net) and download them to your project. As I stated previously, AForge should work seamlessly with Windows Forms, most likely you are missing a third-party reference.